# Firebase DebugView and StreamView

Tags: android, firebase, adb, firebase-analytics

According the [new documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) to starts the real time debug with firebase we need to open adb command and using this following one:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <package_name>
```

To open the cmd (in adb path) I'm going to /sdk/platform-tools with cd and execute the command without errors.

After using this my firebase not detecting my debug device, any ideas?

Comment: Be sure that you enable it for device you're currently using (`adb -e` to target emulator or `adb -d` for real device). Another thing to check is if you target it for proper package name (especially if any debug suffixes or flavor suffixes are used)

Comment: Can you please provide logcat of the app launch. The log cat contains lines explaining if the app is in debug mode and/or debug logs.